# Callers cannot hear me unless I turn on speaker phone!

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, calls, audio, microphone

I have a Samsung Galaxy S2 (SGH-S959G) and it is a Straight Talk phone (don't know if that makes a difference or not). Anyway, I have only had this phone for about 6 or 7 months.

Around August 16, 2013 I noticed that when someone calls me or I call someone I can hear them but they cannot hear me unless I turn on speaker phone. I got in touch with Straight Talk and the representative instructed me to:

- turn the phone off,
- take the battery out,
- take the SIM card out,
- clean the SIM card by wiping it on my shirt or whatnot,
- and then replace the SIM and battery.

He then said to make a call, which I did and it worked.

However, two days later it started back doing the same thing by repeated the instructions listed above in the exact same manner several times and it did not work. It still does not work.

Also, when I call voicemail and change my personal settings, it will record what I say without it being on speaker. So I'm not quite sure why I am able to be heard in that manner but not when talking to someone.

Also, every now and then when I sit my phone down on a counter, the phone will just randomly turn off.

There really is no good reason for that to happen unless I was throwing it down, which I am not. I have always taken good care of my things, especially my $350 phone. It's ridiculous to pay this much and only be able to use it for 6 or 7 months.

Please Help.

Comment: I doubt the SIM card has *anything* to do with the issue, as it's neither connected to the microphone nore to the speakers. As this still (temporarily) fixed your issue – for the reason of the battery being removed – rather suggests something software related. I'd say some driver messes up, or it's a hardware issue with some "flaky contact". Whichever of both, it most likely can only be fixed by the service: they need to figure which of the two is the culprit, and either fix the hardware or re-flash the [radio-firmware](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/radio-firmware/info).

Comment: can you check if skype works fine? (or another WIFI based calling client)
This way I can  tell if it might be a software or hardware issue

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling "Noise Cancellation" on your device.

Answer (score 1):

There are two microphones on your phone: one for speaker and one for non speaker.  You have to clean the mic port on the bottom of your phone with a small pin.

Comment: I agree completely with this answer.  It must be a problem with the microphone.  It could be pocket lint, or maybe something got poked into it (which would most likely destroy it).  Glad you have the speaker option so it is still a useful phone.  But take the advice in this answer and check it out.  You may be able to clean it.  (Just don't use a toothpick).

Answer (score 0):

i got this problem also on my (in the mean while old) S2

there is a connector of the speaker in your phone who is not connected anymore

check youtube movies how to open your phone (not so difficult with correct tools) and connect this connector to the main pcb

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to do factory reset of your device as the problem sounds to be software related. If your mic was to be alright, even the voice mail wouldn't have worked.