# What could cause outgoing phonecall audio to fail?

Tags: audio, calls, troubleshooting

My Moto G6 Play runs Android 9. Some time in the last year or so (I don't make a lot of phone calls) people started telling me they couldn't hear me, or only very quietly, when I called them.

It's not the microphone because I can use that to record audio on an audio-recording app.

It's not the sim because the I can use that in another device without a problem.

It's not the default Google phonecall app because the same problem occurs with e.g. Viber.

Location might be a factor because I've noticed the problem at home (where I make almost all of my rare phonecalls) but people seem to have been able to hear me during some brief outdoor phone calls. On the other hand perhaps I was speaking louder.

Any ideas?

---

**ETA:** It's not a "two microphone" issue because turning on speaker-phone during a call doesn't make a difference.

I can't find any noise-cancelling setting that could be affecting it.

Comment: Are you using headphones, hands free or holding to your face?

Comment: @RohitGupta I've tried both with the same result.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. There are similar questions with more possibilities, like [VoLTE/VoWiFi](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/138809/nexus-5x-no-one-can-hear-me-on-the-phone?rq=1#comment177761_138809), [speakerphone](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/55524/44325), [2 microphones, 1 broken](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/137791/44325) (and more on Related Questions). You might want to browse and try some of them.

Comment: @AndrewT. Thanks for the suggestions. I've added to my OP why I don't think those Q&A's fit my case.